# How to include a custom code field in a view or ds view?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, display-suite

Recently I was playing with display suite views. It's an interesting concept because this allows have content "displays" of a specific content type without adding displays to other content types that might not make sense.

My question arises because there's no way to include my custom code field in a view, despite I already checked my field to be present in "node" & "ds views" entities.

I tried to find my custom field in these 2 locations without success:

- admin/structure/ds/vd/manage/{theNameOfMyView}/display

[image: my custom code field is not here]

- admin/structure/views/view/{theNameOfMyView}

[image: my custom code field is not here]

I read that custom code fields are not exposed to views. If that is so here is my second question: What is the purpose of checking "ds views" fields when adding a "code field" with Display Suite?

[image: custom code field edit screen]

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'DS views' refers to the display format of the [views](https://drupal.org/project/views). 
So you have to use the "**Display Suite**" show format when you create the [views](https://drupal.org/project/views).

[image]

Notice that if you want to have a field in a [views](https://drupal.org/project/views) you have to create it normally and not with DS. That is what the module says.

Comment: By now thanks a lot for your answer. I need to understand the purpose of this specific feature of DS. I can see my custom field if I modify my views template, but that does not make much sense. It would be much more useful if my custom field code appeared on views displays for fields. Thanks!